# WPP like logs using constexpr in C++

Tags: c++, logging, c++14, constexpr

WPP (Windows software trace PreProcessor) is a very neat Win32 infrastructure that implements a very fast logs for C++ using ETW.

One of the key features of WPP is that it takes a formatted message such as *`("Some function got x = %d for y = %s", x, y)`* and replaces the formatted string with UID. The UID and the paramters (x, y in the example) are saved to a log file, without resolving the formatted string. UID and the parameters are resolved at home. The infrastructure is considured very fast becuase both wirting a UID is usally faster than writing a string and format string resolving could be costly in CPU. Another nice side effect is that the Executable is not containing the internal debug strings and it's a bit harder to revers engineer it.

I saw it is possible to caculate a hash of string during compile time using constexpr. The only thing I'm missing in order to create a full portable WPP like in pure C++, is a relaiable C++ way to generate a trnslation table from UID to String in compile time. I want this table not to exists in the EXE I deploy to customers and I prefer it not to relay on another compiling step.
Note that in WPP, the table is saved inside the PDB, this is not necessarily what I'm looking for.